# Nested recursive method calls

Tags: python, recursion

How do nested recursive method calls work in process flow? In the quicksort python code below, the quickSortHelper recursive function calls itself once with the arguments alist, first and splitpoint-1. Then it calls itself again with alist, splitpoint+1, last. How is the program flowing when these calls are made? To me it looks like the second recursive method call would never be reached.

```
def quickSort(alist):
   quickSortHelper(alist,0,len(alist)-1)

def quickSortHelper(alist,first,last):
   if first<last:

       splitpoint = partition(alist,first,last)

       quickSortHelper(alist,first,splitpoint-1)
       quickSortHelper(alist,splitpoint+1,last)


def partition(alist,first,last):
   pivotvalue = alist[first]

   leftmark = first+1
   rightmark = last

   done = False
   while not done:

       while leftmark <= rightmark and alist[leftmark] <= pivotvalue:
           leftmark = leftmark + 1

       while alist[rightmark] >= pivotvalue and rightmark >= leftmark:
           rightmark = rightmark -1

       if rightmark < leftmark:
           done = True
       else:
           temp = alist[leftmark]
           alist[leftmark] = alist[rightmark]
           alist[rightmark] = temp

   temp = alist[first]
   alist[first] = alist[rightmark]
   alist[rightmark] = temp


   return rightmark

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
quickSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The second call will occur after the first returns.

Comment: Both calls will happen, although `quickSortHelper` doesn't return anything...

Comment: Okay, so when `first` is greater than `last`, then it will return to the quickSort function, if I'm understanding it.

Comment: @blm my question is why is there not a loop between the first nested `quickSortHelper` call and the `def quickSortHelper`.

Comment: "Okay, so when first is greater than last, then it will return to the quickSort function" - Not necessarily. When `first >= last`, quickSortHelper will return to *whoever called it*, which can either be `quickSort` or `quickSortHelper` (itself). The fact that it's returning to itself is irrelevant, it just returns to whoever called it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not about python code, it's about **recursion**!!
 So first let me explain what happens when you call a function,say f(), recursively!
first let examine an easy call you might have seen alot:
**1- normal call** : you definitely have faced it alot! is it hard?

```
def g(num):
    return 2*num

def h(num):
    return 2+num

def f(num):
    return g(num)+h(num)
```

**2- normal call again**: this time instead of two different functions(h&g) we call 2 same functions(g) but not the same as caller function(f):this is also easy!

```
def g(num):
    return 2*num

def f(num):
    return g(num)+g(num)
```

**3- recursive call comes!!!**:
now instead of different call, we use the same function as caller:

```
def f(num):
    if num <0 :
        return 0
    return 2+f(num-1)+f(num-2)
```

so if we want to calculate f(num) , we MUST know f(num-1) AND f(num-2).so we have to call their functions and add them together.The important thing is that after we calucated f(num-1)-say equals to 10- we are here at the return statement:

return 2+10+f(num-2)

***so the return statement means, return to were you have been called ! f(num-1) returns to f(num) which called it!***  don't confuse return with exit!

also I added some tracking points for your code to see what happens and what is the order of functions running!

```
count = 0

def quickSort(alist):
  global count
  print "quickSort() and count is",count
  count+=1
  quickSortHelper(alist,0,len(alist)-1)

def quickSortHelper(alist,first,last):
   global count
   print "quickSortHelper() and count is",count
   count+=1
   if first<last:

       splitpoint = partition(alist,first,last)

       print "quickSortHelper(),counting first part"
       quickSortHelper(alist,first,splitpoint-1)
       print "quickSortHelper(),done first part"
       print '#'*10
       print
       print "quickSortHelper(),counting first part"
       quickSortHelper(alist,splitpoint+1,last)


def partition(alist,first,last):
   global count
   print "partition() and count is",count
   count+=1
   pivotvalue = alist[first]

   leftmark = first+1
   rightmark = last

   done = False
   while not done:

       while leftmark <= rightmark and alist[leftmark] <= pivotvalue:
           leftmark = leftmark + 1

       while alist[rightmark] >= pivotvalue and rightmark >= leftmark:
           rightmark = rightmark -1

       if rightmark < leftmark:
           done = True
       else:
           temp = alist[leftmark]
           alist[leftmark] = alist[rightmark]
           alist[rightmark] = temp

   temp = alist[first]
   alist[first] = alist[rightmark]
   alist[rightmark] = temp


   return rightmark

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
quickSort(alist)
print(alist)
```